# Not able to link libraries in React Native

Tags: react-native

I am not able to link the libraries in my react-native project. I tries all the ways in google but it's not helping. When i try to open the signing-config.json file in Atom it says 'EPERM: operation not permitted'

```sh
>react-native link

error No package found. Are you sure this is a React Native project?

error EPERM: operation not permitted, scandir 'E:/<ProjectName>/android/app/build/intermediates/signing_config/debug/out/signing-config.json'. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
```

```sh
>react-native link --verbose

debug Available platforms: iOS, Android

debug Targeted platforms: iOS, Android

debug Getting project config for iOS...

error No package found. Are you sure this is a React Native project?

error EPERM: operation not permitted, scandir 'E:/<ProjectName>/android/app/build/intermediates/signing_config/debug/out/signing-config.json'

debug Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, scandir 'E:/<Projectname>/android/app/build/intermediates/signing_config/debug/out/signing-config.json'

    at Object.readdirSync (fs.js:785:3)
    at GlobSync._readdir (E:\<ProjectName>\node_modules\glob\sync.js:288:41)
    at GlobSync._readdirInGlobStar (E:\<ProjectName>\node_modules\glob\sync.js:267:20)
    at GlobSync._readdir (E:\<ProjectName>\node_modules\glob\sync.js:276:17)
    at GlobSync._processReaddir (E:\<ProjectName>\node_modules\glob\sync.js:137:22)
    at GlobSync._process (E:\<ProjectName>\node_modules\glob\sync.js:132:10)
    at GlobSync._processGlobStar (E:\<ProjectName>\node_modules\glob\sync.js:380:10)
    at GlobSync._process (E:\<ProjectName>\node_modules\glob\sync.js:130:10)
    at GlobSync._processGlobStar (E:\<ProjectName>\node_modules\glob\sync.js:383:10)
    at GlobSync._process (E:\<ProjectName>\node_modules\glob\sync.js:130:10)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was having this problem for many hours but I figured it out late. It was a stupid mistake at my end. The solution is to run **cmd as admin**

Comment: When I ran the command it was not working without admin privileges. It ran only when the admin as toggled on for cmd.

Comment: But I am running the command with admin privileges but am getting same error ...

Comment: @DavidCallanan which version of react-native are you using?

Comment: 0.63.2   --  I think it's a Windows problem though, I have been seeing this error constantly running various commands and even navigating windows explorer.

Comment: If you ran the command as your regular user account then it won't work. When you attempt to run the command again as admin you won't be the owner of `signing-config.json` and you will get this error.
Just delete the file `E:/<ProjectName>/android/app/build/intermediates/signing_config/debug/out/signing-config.json` and run the command again as admin and it will build.